# Format Picture with Fill and Line using apache poi in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am inserting image in excel using apache poi 3.15 its working file but I want to add border line to image which can be done by **right click on image --> Format Picture --> Fill & Line --> Line --> Solid Line in MS Office** searched a lot on SO and apache documentation but have no clue how to achieve this using poi. Following my code

```
private void drawImageOnExcelSheetForGLOS(XSSFSheet sitePhotosSheet,
        int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2, String fileName) {
    try {

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        int pictureIdx = sitePhotosSheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(bytes,Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
        is.close();
        CreationHelper helper = sitePhotosSheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

        // Create the drawing patriarch. This is the top level container for
        // all shapes.
        Drawing drawing = sitePhotosSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        // add a picture shape
        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setAnchorType( ClientAnchor.MOVE_AND_RESIZE );


        // set top-left corner of the picture,
        // subsequent call of Picture#resize() will operate relative to it
        anchor.setCol1(col1);
        anchor.setCol2(col2);
        anchor.setRow1(row1);
        anchor.setRow2(row2);

        drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I am able to draw line around image using XSSFSimpleShape but it is not what I wanted exactly and also tried with setBorderXXX() but these borders or lines do not move with image as when set using MS Office.
First image show what I am getting and second shows what I want
[image]

Comment: The `drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);` is not a void method. It returns a [XSSFPicture](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFPicture.html). This extends [XSSFShape](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFShape.html) and inherits some `setLine...` methods. Have you tried using those methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by using XSSFPicture's setLineXXX() method as follows,

```
private void drawImageOnExcelSheetForGLOS(XSSFSheet sitePhotosSheet,
        int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2, String fileName) {
    try {

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        int pictureIdx = sitePhotosSheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(bytes,Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
        is.close();
        CreationHelper helper = sitePhotosSheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

        XSSFDrawing drawing = sitePhotosSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setAnchorType( ClientAnchor.MOVE_AND_RESIZE );

        anchor.setCol1(col1);
        anchor.setCol2(col2);
        anchor.setRow1(row1);
        anchor.setRow2(row2);

        // setLineXXX() methods can be used to set line border to image
        XSSFPicture pic = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
        // 0 indicates solid line
        pic.setLineStyle(0);
        // rgb color code for black line
        pic.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);
        // double number for line width
        pic.setLineWidth(1.5);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```