# How to add image with border into table cell in Word with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, border, xwpf

I am trying to insert a picture with a border into a table in Microsoft Word with Apache POI. I am able to add an image into a cell with the code below:

```
// table is a XWPFTable object instantiated earlier in the code
XWPFParagraph paragraph = table.getRow(0).getCell(0).addParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\ [filepath for the image]");
run.addPicture(fis, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "Name", 6217920, 3474720);
```

I tried looking for ways to add a border to the image, but I haven't been able to find any resources online. I came across this link: [Format Picture with Fill and Line using apache poi in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248697/format-picture-with-fill-and-line-using-apache-poi-in-java) but it does not help in this case.

(To be specific, I want to add a solid black line which is 2 1/4 pt thick around the image)

Does anybody know how to do achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always if the current high level `apache poi` classes not provide some `Office Open XML` features, do the following:

First do what is provided and have a look at the underlying `XML` you get created. In that case, do:

```
// table is a XWPFTable object instantiated earlier in the code
XWPFParagraph paragraph = table.getRow(0).getCell(0).addParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\ [filepath for the image]");
XWPFPicture picture = run.addPicture(fis, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "Name", Units.pixelToEMU(300), Units.pixelToEMU(150));
System.out.println(picture.getCTPicture());
```

You will get something like:

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:rel="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
  <pic:nvPicPr>
    <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="Picture 0" descr="Name"/>
    <pic:cNvPicPr>
      <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="true"/>
    </pic:cNvPicPr>
  </pic:nvPicPr>
  <pic:blipFill>
    <a:blip rel:embed="rId2"/>
    <a:stretch>
      <a:fillRect/>
    </a:stretch>
  </pic:blipFill>
  <pic:spPr>
    <a:xfrm>
      <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
      <a:ext cx="2857500" cy="1428750"/>
    </a:xfrm>
    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
      <a:avLst/>
    </a:prstGeom>
  </pic:spPr>
</xml-fragment>
```

Now open the result in `Word` and add what you want. In that case add the border around the picture. Then save the result, unzip the `*.docx` `Zip` archive and have a look at `/word/document.xml` to get what has changed.

You will find something like:

```
<a:ln w="28575">
  <a:solidFill>
    <a:srgbClr val="000000"/>
  </a:solidFill>
</a:ln>
```

added to `<pic:spPr>`.

Now try creating that using the low level `ooxml-schema` classes of `apache poi`:

```
...
XWPFPicture picture = run.addPicture(fis, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "Name", Units.pixelToEMU(300), Units.pixelToEMU(150));
System.out.println(picture.getCTPicture());

picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().addNewLn().setW(Units.toEMU(2.25));
picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getLn().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{0,0,0});
System.out.println(picture.getCTPicture());
...
```